# One of the channels for dual channel mode is disabled

Tags: memory, motherboard

I'm trying to install 4 RAM sticks on a Gigabyte P55 UD3 mobo but I'm having problems with that.

As you can see in the picture attached, the 2 rams that are installed in slots 3 and 4 are disabled. I switched their places and still the result was the same.

I can only get 2 DIMM slots to work I don't know why.

Though the mobo recognizes the rams and gives me a total of 12 GB of RAM, it still shows that 6 or 8 GB of the total RAM (depending on the placement of the sticks) is "Hardware Reserved"!

[image: picture]

I have all the installed sticks on the mainboard info list.

- 2x 2 GB and 2x 4 GB

One of each is working and the total is 6 GB of RAM available.

On the "Enabled Slots" 2 of the slots are disabled and there is only a " - " in their info column.

Answer (score 2):

I have the same motherboard ([hardware revision 1.0](https://www.gigabyte.com/Motherboard/GA-P55A-UD3-rev-10) with F11 BIOS) and the same memory configuration (2 × 4 GB + 2 × 2 GB) as well as a [Lynnfield processor](http://ark.intel.com/products/codename/29896/Lynnfield), though mine is a Core i7 860.  **TL;DR** This worked for a few years until the same problem started happening: all 12 GB is recognized in the BIOS, but only DIMM slots 1 and 2 are enabled, leaving only 6 GB usable.  In my case, this is apparently caused by a bad memory module.

When I built this system I started off with a [G.SKILL ECO F3-12800CL8D-4GBECO 2 × 2 GB kit](https://www.gskill.com/en/product/f3-12800cl8d-4gbeco), and that worked fine.  A few years ago I added a [Crucial Ballistix Tactical BLT2K4G3D1608ET3LX0 2 × 4 GB kit](http://www.crucial.com/usa/en/blt2k4g3d1608et3lx0) (yes, different manufacturer and size) in DIMM slots 1 and 3, and moved the G.SKILL modules to slots 2 and 4.  This also worked fine.  Here's a screenshot I took a couple years ago showing the BIOS correctly recognizing and enabling all available memory:

[image: GIGABYTE GA-P55A-UD3 BIOS with 2 × 4 GB + 2 × 2 GB memory modules enabled]

So, the memory configuration in question is possible because I've successfully run it that way for nearly three years without issue.  Yesterday I noticed Windows 10 Task Manager reporting that I only had 6 GB of total memory, with the other 6 GB "hardware reserved".  When I went to investigate I found the BIOS reporting my memory configuration exactly the same as the `DIMM(s)` section of the screenshot in the question.

The way I isolated this to a bad memory module is for each of the four modules I installed it by itself in slot 1 and tried booting, then installed it by itself in slot 3 and tried booting.  For both G.SKILL modules and one of the Crucial modules, in either slot the system would boot and correctly recognize the installed memory.  For the other Crucial module, the system would not boot with it in either slot; it would power on, but the display never came on, there were no beep codes, and it would not POST.

Additionally, for each kit I tried booting with the modules installed in slots 1 and 3, then swapped the modules around (1→3 and 3→1) and tried booting again.  With the G.SKILL kit the system booted and recognized and enabled both modules.  With the Crucial kit the system also booted and recognized both modules, but only one module was enabled.  In fact, in one of the two permutations (I think with the bad module in slot 1) I was able to get this screenshot of a nonsensical memory configuration where the only slot listed as enabled is one of the **empty** ones:

[image: GIGABYTE GA-P55A-UD3 BIOS with 2 × 4 GB memory modules installed; 1 module is bad]

Finally, I ran [Memtest86+](http://www.memtest.org/) with every configuration (alone and with other modules installed) of modules that booted and it passed every time.  When I had the bad module installed with its sibling Memtest86+ recognized that there was 8 GB of memory installed, but only tested the 4 GB that was enabled, so it was not possible to test the bad module.

Another issue I've noticed the last few weeks that I can confirm is related to this is every *odd*-numbered time I'd try to boot (whether it was from the hard drive or a network boot), the BIOS logo would appear, the AHCI controller would enumerate the drives, and once the text "Loading operating system ..." would appear, the system would completely power off.  A few seconds later, it would power itself back on and only then (on the second attempt) would it successfully boot whatever I wanted to boot.  If I restarted the system, it would happen all over again: power itself off shortly into the third boot attempt, power itself back on, and successfully boot on the fourth attempt.

Despite there being no error messages to work with, I eventually found that this is caused by having a single enabled module in the first pair of slots (1 and 3).  When my bad module died it left the good module unpaired in either slot 1 or 3, plus the two good G.SKILL modules in slots 2 and 4.  Even after removing the bad module from the system and leaving everything else the same, it still meant there was an unpaired module in slot 1 or 3.  In both cases I had only 6 GB of RAM usable despite having 8 GB of good modules installed:

[image: GIGABYTE GA-P55A-UD3 BIOS with 2 × 2 GB + 1 × 2 GB memory modules installed; one module disabled when pair installed in slots 2 and 4]

Perhaps this will help someone else because I was not aware of it (never had to deal with an odd number of DDR modules until now), but the fix is to make sure that the paired modules are in slots 1 and 3, and then the remaining module(s) get installed starting with slot 2:

[image: GIGABYTE GA-P55A-UD3 BIOS with 2 × 2 GB + 1 × 2 GB memory modules installed; all modules enabled when pair installed in slots 1 and 3]

Once I made this change I had 8 GB of RAM usable out of the 8 GB installed, and my system would no longer power itself off and back on every other boot attempt.  Now I just need to see if Crucial will (hopefully) replace the failed module under warranty so I can get back to 2 × 4 GB + 2 × 2 GB = 12 GB usable.

Answer (score 0):

You should place the matching capacity modules in the same channel. So try putting your two 4 GB modules in channel 0 and your two 2 GB modules in channel 1. As per the reference below.

Taken from:
http://www.manualslib.com/manual/452671/Gigabyte-Ga-P55a-Ud3.html?page=16

> 1-4-1 Dual Channel Memory Configuration
>
> This motherboard provides four DDR3 memory sockets and supports Dual Channel Technology. After the memory is installed, the BIOS will automatically detect the specifications and capacity of the memory.  Enabling Dual Channel memory mode will double the original memory bandwidth.The four DDR3 memory sockets are divided into two channels and each channel has two memory sockets as following:
>
> Channel 0: DDR3_1, DDR3_2
>
> Channel 1: DDR3_3, DDR3_4
>
> Due to CPU limitations, read the following guidelines before installing the memory in Dual Channel mode.
>
> 1. Dual Channel mode cannot be enabled if only one DDR3 memory module is installed.
> 2. When enabling Dual Channel mode with two or four memory modules, it is recommended that memory of the same capacity, brand, speed, and chips be used for optimum performance.
>
> When enabling Dual Channel mode with two memory modules, be sure to install them in the DDR3_1 and DDR3_3 sockets.

Comment: The text you cite does not provide support either for or against your suggestion. The only line that really touches on your point is the last one, and that's just saying what to do if you have exactly two modules to install.  At any rate, and I don't have a citation for this, but I'm pretty sure when you've got two matched pairs of memory to install, you want both channels to have the same amount of RAM. If you didn't do this (e.g. channel A had 2 × 4 GB = 8 GB and channel B had 2 × 2 GB = 4 GB), it couldn't interleave operations beyond the first 4 GB, thus dual channel mode would be disabled.